# Compiling VS2015 project with VS2010 Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Ok so I am using VS2015 and upgraded an old VC++ 2010 project to run and compile just fine with VS2015. The project is a windows form project using CLR.

I recently discovered that the project will now not run on a vista machine which until recently was what I was doing the development on. I'm guessing the main culprit is the lack of .NET 4.5 on the vista machine. So I decided to try and compile it with VS 2010 toolset and compilers to see if it would work on this machine.

I downloaded and installed all the tool chains SDK 7.1 and the 7.1 update so now when I go into the

```
project properties > platform toolset
```

I have multiple options to compile for VS 2015 v140, VS 2013 v120, SDK7.1 etc and VS 2010 v100.

The problem I have is that when attempting to compile I get the following errors.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(297,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.


1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(62,5): error : Required file "" is missing.
```

A secondary problem I came across is that I switch between managed String^ and regular std::string. To do this, I am using marshalling. When selecting the VS2010 toolset, the following code generates errors.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace msclr::interop;
```

This obviously has knock on effects for parts of my code where I wish to marshal strings between managed and std.

Anyone got any suggestions on how to fix either of these problems? Thanks

Comment: .NET 4.5 *is* available on Vista. It isn't available on Windows XP. BTW the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. You should try and troubleshoot the original problem instead of trying to use incompatible tools

Comment: Besides, C++ itself changed a *lot* in the last 6 years. `std::string` is an ASCII string while .NET uses Unicode. Back then you had to use the non-Unicode `std::wstring` or `wchar`  types while today C++ has honest-to-god Unicode types and literals, eg `std::u16string` and `char16_t`

Comment: Ok i didn't realize Vista supported .NET 4.5.  So compiling using the 2015 toolset is fine by me. the target architecture is set to Win32, as initially I thought I might be compiling to 64 bit machine and attempting to run 64 bit program on a 32 bit machine.  However, the program doesn't work. Attempting to run it on the Vista machine results in a "Program stopped Working" error dialog.

Comment: What was the error in the Event Viewer? If it's a `bad image` then yes, it's a matter of bitness. I think the `Program stopped Working` dialog has a details button but anyway, crashes are logged in the Event log

Comment: Ok, so it came up Unhandled Exception.  System.TypeInitialisationError Source .NET Framework

Comment: This means that the .NET code run but some constructor crashed. The text of the event should have more details. Check the [TypeInitializationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for probable causes. Since the .NET code run, you could have caught and logged the exception before allowing the application to crash. You can also add an unhandled exception handler to your C++ application so that it logs the errors before terminating

Comment: Will attempt that.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure how to catch this TypeInitializationError and have found that the program throws the same errors on windows 7 and other windows 10 machines.... I am at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: The program throws because it has a bug. Without any code, one can only give generic debugging and error logging advice. Try debugging the application on a clean machine to reproduce the problem. In production, you need to have logging to record such problems. Add exception handlers to your library's entry points and log the exception text using whatever logging library you have eg log4net. `Exception.ToString()` returns the full exception, including the call stack and any inner exceptions. That will show you which class crashed.

Comment: So I have figured this out at last. I created a setup project and made sure that that it included the Visual C++ 14 redist as a per-requiste along with .NET 4.6 and Windows Installer 4.5.  Under Launch Conditions, I made sure that .NET Framework version was the same as the Project Properties (in this case 4.5.2). This yielded a setup program as well as the main project installation.msi.  Running the setup program caused it dl the VC++ redist, it then ran the msi and voila.... program worked.  I also updated .NET on the target machine just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just going to go ahead an post my solution for this. **There is no need to use the VS2010 V100 toolset.**

First, I updated the target machine to .NET 4.6. I think the latest is 4.6.2.

I then created a **Setup Project** for my Solution and called it **'Prog Setup'**. I included **"primary output"** and **"resource satellite DLLs"** within the setup projects' **'Detected Dependencies'**. The wizard was helpful in setting this up.

Next, Right Click on the Setup Project, select **'View > Launch Conditions'**, Right Click on **.NET Framework**, select **'Properties'**
Now check **'version'** is set to the same version as main project. In my case 4.5.2.

Finally, right click on the setup project and select **'Properties'**, Now select **'Configuration dropdown > Release'**, Click **'Prerequisites'** and select **.NET 4.6, VC++ 14 Runtime Libraries (x86 / x64), Windows Installer 4.5.**

Ok, now from the menu bar **'Build > configuration manager', ensure both the setup project and main project are checked under the 'Build' column** to ensure both projects are built.

Run the build / re-build project.  Using the standard VS2015 v140 Toolset.

In the project solution folder, locate the following

**VS2015 > Projects > Project Name > Prog Setup > Release**

this folder contains an application titled '**Setup**' and my '**Prog Setup**' Windows Installer Package.

Having done all the above, I copied both packages to a USB stick and then on the target machine, ran the Application **'Setup'**.

This then went and downloaded and installed the VC++ 14 Runtime Libraries on the target machine. Following this, it then automatically ran **Prog Setup** which installed the actual program software and voila... it now runs on the target machine.